# how to check if the content of two files are the same?

Tags: c

I need to check if the content of the two files is the same, I mean if the string in each file is equal to each other. I wrote a program in c language with a function that if the files are the same will return 2 otherwise return 1. My problem is that the function keeps return 1 no matter what is the content.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int compareFilles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2){

  int word1 = getc(fp1); 
  int word2 = getc(fp2);

  //A loop until the end of the files(EOF)
  while (word1 =! EOF && word2 != EOF && word1 == word2){
    word1 = getc(fp1); 
    word2 = getc(fp2);
  }

  if (word1 != word2){
     return 1;
   }else{
        return 2;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE *fp1 = fopen(argv[0], "r");
  FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[1], "r");

  printf("%d", compareFilles(fp1, fp2));

  //closing the files
  fclose(fp1); 
  fclose(fp2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `word1 =! EOF` which is `word1 = (!EOF)` which is an assignment.

Comment: OT: A `do-while` loop would be more suitable here.

Comment: Rudimentary debugging steps would have revealed the problem: Print `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` or examine them in a debugger. Examine the characters being processed by `compareFilles`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying about the not equal operators (I'm new to c language) but when I change to word1 = (!EOF) I get an error of 'expression must be a modifiable lvalue'.
Again I'm new to this language and must of my time I program with JAVA so again sorry for my question

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `argv[0]` contains the command used to start the program, usually the name of the executable file or part of it. Thus, your program is comparing its own executable file to the file named by the first argument (`argv[1]`), and they are different.

Comment: Aaaaannnnnnddd what if the first argument of the program is the path of the program itself ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int compareFilles(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2){
```

This function should return a `bool` since that is the natural data type for expressing a `true/false` value.

```
  int word1 = getc(fp1); 
  int word2 = getc(fp2);
```

The variable names are wrong. The `getc` function does not read a word, it only reads a single byte from a file.

```
  //A loop until the end of the files(EOF)
  while (word1 =! EOF && word2 != EOF && word1 == word2){
```

As said in one of the comments, the `=!` means "assign negative" instead of the "unequal" you meant. To avoid this kind of mistakes in the future, always let an automatic code formatter format your code before it is saved to disk. Then that code would have been shown as `word1 = !EOF`, which should draw enough attention. Doing this will also protect you from the famous [goto fail](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) bug, which means you will have a better programming standard than Apple. That sounds like a lot, doesn't it?

Plus, always enable all compiler warnings. The compiler would have warned you about an "assignment in a condition, which is often not intended", which is exactly the case here.

```
    word1 = getc(fp1); 
    word2 = getc(fp2);
  }

  if (word1 != word2){
     return 1;
   }else{
        return 2;
    }
}
```

If your function returns `bool`, that last `if` statement should simply be replaced with `return word1 == word2`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE *fp1 = fopen(argv[0], "r");
  FILE *fp2 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

The error checking is missing here. If either of `fp1` or `fp2` is NULL, the program must handle this error.

```
  printf("%d", compareFilles(fp1, fp2));

  //closing the files
  fclose(fp1); 
  fclose(fp2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I new to C programming and all the other function I've found beside getc needs a somewhere to store each word that its read and a size, in my program I don't know how much words there is in any file. I found fgets and fscanf but both need array and size... appreciate the help really